# PHP - Replace URL in text with Links OR Images

Tags: php, regex

Doesn't matter how much I try, I can't figure this out.
I have a comments section on my website and I have some functions using regex expressions.
One of mine functions replaces URLs in the content string in links, as long as it can, it is working pretty well. But I wanted to check if the match is a normal link or if it is an image (ends with .jpg, .gif, etc) if so, it should then have the replace expression with `<img>` tags.
What I have so for:

```
function url_parse($string) {
    $string = preg_replace('/\b(?:(http(s?):\/\/)|(?=www\.))(\S+)/is', '<a href="http$2://$3" target="_blank">$1$3</a>', $string);
    return $string; 
}
```

This one is the function to replace the links. Easy as that. But my idea to check if it is a image, I made alot of confusions here. I don't even know how to extact the link, so I do this:

```
function geturl($string) {
    $regex = '/\b(?:(http(s?):\/\/)|(?=www\.))(\S+)/is';
    preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
    return ($matches[0]);
}
```

I even made a function to check if it is actually a link to a image

```
function isIMG($url){
    $ext = strrpos( $url, ".");
    if ($pos === false) {
        return false;
    }
    $ext = strtolower(trim(substr( $url, $pos)));
    $exts = array(".gif", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".tiff", ".tif");
    if (in_array($ext, $exts)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
       return false;
    }
}
```

But, I got myself into a LIMBO. I just can't put it all working together. I tried everything... Any help?

The objective here is:

1. Check if the URL extracted from the string is a normal link OR if it have an image ext.
2. `preg_replace` in the string.
   I hope that this question doesn't seem messed up. Really needing any help here.

Comment: What about making a request to the URL and seeing what the response is? `if(@exif_imagetype('URL')) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex, with insensitive case:

```
\.(?:gif|jpe?g|tiff?|png)$
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/mY1pX5/1)

And, if there is a match againt `$url` then it is one of your images.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Using your answer, I correct my function and I was able to do what I want. But after that, I decided to put all image links into an array and show all at once as thumbnails in the end of the `$content` for now on, it works like a charm. Thanks